# Pass existing php array to jquery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I have a PHP array I want to pass to my jquery (replace the test array with my php array).

```
Array
(
    [12] => Some Text
    [6] => Another text
    [11] => one more text
)
```

Jquery:

```
$('#SearchUser').typeahead({
                source: [
                    { ID: 1, Name: 'Toronto' },
                    { ID: 2, Name: 'Montreal' },
                    { ID: 3, Name: 'New York' },
                    { ID: 4, Name: 'Buffalo' },
                    { ID: 5, Name: 'Boston' },
                    { ID: 6, Name: 'Columbus' },
                    { ID: 7, Name: 'Dallas' },
                    { ID: 8, Name: 'Vancouver' },
                    { ID: 9, Name: 'Seattle' },
                    { ID: 10, Name: 'Los Angeles' }
                ],
                display: 'Name',
                val: 'ID',
                itemSelected: updateID
            });
```

So how can I set the var for "source" to my php array?

Suggestions?

As always,, you are awesome!

-Tom

Comment: Can you link to the typeahead plugin you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I'd done it in one of my projects was,

```
$.get("<?= $baseUrl ?>search/data", function (data) {
    var dataObject = JSON.parse(data);
    $('#q').typeahead({
        'source': dataObject,
        // 'items': 5
    });
});
```

and my search controller's data method is:

```
echo (json_encode($arr)); // $arr is ["a","b","c"] etc. but you can have an associated array too.
```

Basically, the point of showing my code is to say use `json`

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_encode function of php to conver a php array to json. Then you can use the json as javascript array.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

I don't know how you get data from php code to javascript code, but if you print data as json, you can take it via an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's `json_encode()` function to create a string that is a valid JSON, and then read that with jQuery's `$.getJSON()`.

Something like this:

**get_array.php**

```
$someArray = /* whatever */;
echo json_encode($someArray);
```

**read_array.js**

```
$.getJSON('get_array.php', function(data) {
    // data now contains your array
});
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var someArray = <?php echo json_encode($someArray); ?>
</script>
```

If you don't want the separate files and don't mind using a global variable for it.

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jsArray = <?php echo json_encode($phpArray); ?>
</script>
```

but it is a bad practice to mix language X with language Y.

Well, take a look at my answer to this post in which you can do the following in a better way:

[Is echoing Javascript code condtionally based on server-side logic considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658596/is-echoing-javascript-code-condtionally-based-on-server-side-logic-considered-ha/11658716#11658716)

Hope this helps :-)