# How to access the value of an element detected by livequery

Tags: php, jquery

I am using $_SESSION to pass back a value in the event of page redirect.

As jquery cannot access $_SESSION I decided to use PHP to output the value to a hidden div and remove that div once the value had been picked up. I expect that there is a neater way to do this but I don't know how else to expose the $_SESSION variable to jquery.

```
<?php       
    $pass_Back = $session->get_Pass_Back();
    $session->clear_Pass_Back();
?>

<?php
    if (count($pass_Back) != 0){
        echo "<input class=\"field_Input_Left\" id=\"schedule_Description\" type=\"text\" name=\"schedule_Description\" value=\"" . array_shift($pass_Back) . "\"/><br />";
        echo "<div id=\"pass_Back\" style=\"visibilty: hidden;\" ></div>";
    } else {    
        echo "<input class=\"field_Input_Left\" id=\"schedule_Description\" type=\"text\" name=\"schedule_Description\"/><br />";
    }
?>
```

Once this was done I needed a method to let jquery know if and when this new element was added to the DOM. Hence I used the plugin livequery to match when the element added. This it does which is great.

But when I try to access the value in the div it states that it is undefined.

```
$("#pass_Back").livequery(function(){
    if ($("#class_Name").val() != 0){
        var class_Name = $("#class_Name").val();
        get_Schedule_Data(class_Name);
    } else {
        var class_Name = "ALL";
        get_Schedule_Data(class_Name);
    }   


    $value = $(this).attr("value");
    auto_Fill_Schedule($("#pass_Back").attr("value"));

    // destroy pass back

    $("#pass_Back").remove();
});
```

When reviewed in firebug I note that at the point that livequery finds the added element no html is displayed. The DOM is ready otherwise the livequery couldn't have functioned but is this why no value is found?

Any guideance gratefully received.

Comment: If it's regular redirect and your using PHP to output the HTML, why on earth would you need livequery ?

Comment: The *neater* way to do this would be using [cookies](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2007/05/php-and-javascript-cookie.html)

Comment: Hi @adeneo I want to control the page dynamically through the jquery script by reusing the scripts used to create the original page. The PHP is simply to output the value to somewhere where Jquery can see it. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: If you output the element directly in the HTML, i.e not by getting the values thru `ajax`, you can just check if the element exists and get the value. Also, it looks like you are trying to `echo` an array in PHP, wich will not work, you will either have to `print_r()` it or implode it into a string, see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Don't use this:**

```
$value = $(this).attr("value");
```

---

Do the following to get a value (for inputs in most of cases):

*(assuming `$(this)` is your input)*

```
$value = $(this).val();
```

For `div` cases, there is no `value`, but you can get the `html` or `text` from inside as the value:

*(assuming `$(this)` is your div)*

```
$value = $(this).html();
//or:
$value = $(this).text();
```

---

**Just to know...**

You can mix PHP with jQuery but take a look at my answer from this post for better understanding:

[Is echoing Javascript code condtionally based on server-side logic considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658596/is-echoing-javascript-code-condtionally-based-on-server-side-logic-considered-ha/11658716#11658716)

Comment: Hi @Ocsar I had previously attempted to use both $(this).html() and $(this).text() before attempting to get at the value  through the attribute. I have just tried this again and it does not work. I do howvever not the different methods of getting the value out.

Comment: Hi @Oscar omg that is so obvious now! I have spent way too long looking at this! confusing myself. OK yes of course the obvious omission is that somewhere along the way I have managed to take out the code to populate the div with the value!!! hence .html() and .text() couldn't find anything!! How stupid am I!! Ok so I have sorted that bit out. Now I am going to look a mixng PHP with Jquery. That seems counter intuitive but could be very useful. Thx

Answer (score 1):

As long you're not outputting the entire $_SESSION array, or anything of importance, you're going to be ok:

```
<?php       
    $pass_Back = $session->get_Pass_Back();
    $session->clear_Pass_Back();

    if (count($pass_Back) != 0){
        echo '<div id="passBack" type="text" value="'.implode(",", array_shift($pass_Back)).'" />';
    }
 ?>
```

JS

```
 $(function() {
     if ($("#passBack").length) {
         //element exists in DOM, get the value
         var passBack_data = this.value;
         //do something with the value
     }
 });
```

Just output the element and make sure it's a string, not an array ( I used `implode()` ), and on pageload see if it exists (has length), and get the value.

Comment: Hi @adeneo ok I haven't used implode before so I will go read up on that. If I understand correctly you could use the native javascript onpageload in the jquery script to check that the element has length after the whole page has loaded. Rather than using livequery to capture the addition of the element from .ready onwards. I did attempt to detect length at the outset from .ready but it had no length point hence my search came up with livequery. You expressed concern that I would use livequery to detect the addition of the div. Is this because it is bad in some way? or just not necessary? Thx

Comment: If the element is'nt dynamic, i.e. if it is'nt added with ajax later on but is added with PHP on the serverside before the page is sent to the browser you don't need a plugin, all you have to do is check if the element exist. Also view the source in the browser to see if the element is actually added to the DOM. Again, echo will not display arrays, you need a string.