# Write javascript code in PHP

Tags: javascript, ajax

My index.php

```
    switch ($action){

         case "calendar":

         echo "<script language=\"javascript\">\n";

         echo "document.write('Hello World!')";

         echo "</script>";

         include($_STR_TEMPLATEPATH."/calendar_view.php");

         break;

    }
```

my calendar_view.php:

I have an ajax function which should call the `action` `calendar` from the `index` and display the result on `calendar_view.php` in `calendar div`

```
<script>
    function calendarList()
    {
    var xmlHttp;
    try
      {
      // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
      xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    catch (e)
      {
      // Internet Explorer
      try
        {
        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
      catch (e)
        {
        try
          {
          xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        catch (e)
          {
          alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
          return false;
          }
        }
      }
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 && xmlHttp.status==200)
      {
      document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
      }
    }

      xmlHttp.open("GET","?action=calendar",true);

      xmlHttp.send(null);

    }
  </scritp>
```

The calendar div:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

When I call the `calendarList function` it did call the case, but did not display the result in `calendar div`.

Any help. Thanks

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11658596/is-echoing-javascript-code-condtionally-based-on-server-side-logic-considered-ha/11658717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to display there. If everything works like you described, the response is appended to the DOM, but the JavaScript-alert will never be executed.

Try `alert(xmlHttp.responseText);` to be absolutely sure that your response is correct. If it is, you can go from there.

Comment: I added alert(xmlHttp.responseText); to the script but nothing come out

Comment: But, if I open the inspect element with Firebug in FireFox and open the request "GET" under Response I can see it prints out the script

Comment: @alkhader: Then it MUST alert your response when you use `alert(xmlHttp.responseText);`.

Comment: Yes Got it. It alerts the scripts now,

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a script to write thee text just output text

```
switch ($action){
     case "calendar":
     echo "Hello World!";
     include($_STR_TEMPLATEPATH."/calendar_view.php");
     break;
}
```

I don't think inserting scripts with innerHTML works see [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Comment: Thank you, the text example just to make my post easy. Actually I need to write a complex script.